# Linking to a page in a custom wordpress theme nav bar

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I kind of new in making a site with wordpress and i am having issues with linking my pages on the navbar. I tried linking it with the normal `href="../test.php"` but it stays on the index.php. I tried linking it by doing this:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/test.php">This is a link</a>
```

but when i get on the page, it can only display text. When i add css to it, it only displays a white screen. I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I think you need to go through a wordpress theme development tutorial to get better understanding. This is the first link i got from google : https://www.taniarascia.com/developing-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch/ Hope this helps.

Comment: are you adding the pages on the dashboard or are you hard coding the nav bar? if your are coding on a template then try `<?php echo site_url();?>/page` where page is the name of the page u wanna link without the .php ext

Comment: You can create a [custom page template](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/) with your test.php then make a page and then you can able to add it to wordpress menu

Comment: I think if found out how to do it. Big thanks!